# Double click text to make it copy-able

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've got a loads of tables nested in eachother with background images and loads of frames etc which makes copying text from the page almost impossible. is there a javascript it jquery that would make the area almost like a textfield where you can copy the text easily (not paste just copy)?

Comment: How exactly is it difficult? Could you please post some sample page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This has been discussed before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985272/jquery-selecting-text-in-an-element-akin-to-highlighting-with-your-mouse)

Hopefully the above link will help.

Answer (score 1):

There's a .dblclick() event in jQuery that you could probably rely on.

http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/